# density meaning in the pdf

Tags: calculus, probability

I was reading this article in wikipedia:

Suppose a species of bacteria typically lives 4 to 6 hours. What is the probability that a bacterium lives exactly 5 hours? The answer is 0%. A lot of bacteria live for approximately 5 hours, but there is no chance that any given bacterium dies at exactly 5.0000000000... hours.

Instead we might ask: What is the probability that the bacterium dies between 5 hours and 5.01 hours? Let's say the answer is 0.02 (i.e., 2%). Next: What is the probability that the bacterium dies between 5 hours and 5.001 hours? The answer is probably around 0.002, since this is 1/10th of the previous interval. The probability that the bacterium dies between 5 hours and 5.0001 hours is probably about 0.0002, and so on.

**In these three examples, the ratio (probability of dying during an interval) / (duration of the interval) is approximately constant, and equal to 2 per hour (or 2 hour−1).** For example, there is 0.02 probability of dying in the 0.01-hour interval between 5 and 5.01 hours, and (0.02 probability / 0.01 hours) = 2 hour−1. This quantity 2 hour−1 is called the probability density for dying at around 5 hours.

What does the 2 per hour mean? that 2 bacterias die in 1 hour? I am trying to understand what that ratio means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we refer to the probability measure for a *continuous* random variable to occur in *an interval*, as a *probability mass*, then the derivative at a point in the interval is named by analogy as the *probability density*.

It is the rate of change of the cumulative distribution function relative to the random variable, evaluated at that specific point.

$$\left.\dfrac{\mathrm d \mathsf P(X\leqslant x)}{\mathrm d x\qquad\quad\;}\right\rvert_{x=5\mathrm{hour}}=2\mathrm{hour}^{-1} \qquad=\lim\limits_{x\mapsto 0} \frac{\mathsf P(x < X\leqslant x+\Delta x)}{\Delta x}$$

So for intervals *near enough* to that time you can *approximate* the probability of a bacterium death occurring in that tiny interval.

$$\mathsf P(5\mathrm{hour}< X\leqslant 5.001\mathrm{hour})\approx 0.001\mathrm{hour}\cdot 2\mathrm{hour}^{-1}$$

This is an Intro. to Calculus level topic, is all.

Comment: ok, but for example lets take velocity. lets suppose velocity is 100meters per hour, if i keep this rate constant by an hour I wold have moved 100 meters. what I dont get is the meaning of those 2 per hour, of that were a constsnt rate, what it means, that after an hour 2 bacterias died? if so how i got from probability over an interval to that number?

Comment: It is just the change in *cumulative probability* of death at that time (it is not a constant rate), not in the bacteria themselves.